# Android dialog animation on dismiss

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I'm trying to animate a dialog to move and scale down to the corner of the **screen** on dismiss.
my problem is that the animation is limited only to the dialog borders so the dialog scale and move to the corner of the **dialog**.
If I use:
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.MyAnimation;
(Where MyAnimation has the scale down and move to corner animation) it works well, but my problem is has to be set before the dialog.show(), and I need to decide if to use the animation only before the dismiss (after show was called).
any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am having a similar issue wondering if you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .show() at the beginning of the activity and use .setVisibility(INVISIBLE).
Then on dismiss, scale it as you want it to be scaled and use .setVisibility(VISIBLE)

EDIT : To use this solution, you have to make your own dialog view from View class

Comment: you can not setVisibility on a dialog. you can do it on the root view but it is not good.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I said it because I usually make my own dialog views, I'm editing